# What's the meaning of 'hit the dip'?

Tags: meaning

> And fuck it, let's just see what happens, take a risk, let's take a trip
>
> We swervin' off the bourbon, hope we don't hit the dip

It's from a song, I have found it means to leave, but it seems here the meaning is other. I can presume it means to crash in the car becase they take a trip, but... Help me please

Comment: Which song?  Remember, lyrics often don't mean much, they just sound good.  Dip rhymes with trip. At any rate "hit the dip" is not a common English idiom.

Comment: @James K, oh I think I got the sense of these two lines because of you, thank you! (Lil Xan & Charli XCX - Moonlight)

Comment: this is just a theory, maybe he is using it as a substitute for ditch (BTW, i looked up the lyrics, and the song is called "moonlight")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song is referring to taking a trip and the car is 'swervin' (swerving) off the bourbon, which means that it's not driving in a straight line because the driver is drunk. Based on the scene being described, I think that 'hit the dip', means to drive too fast over a dip in the road.

A 'dip' is a place where there is a depression in the road that goes all the way across the road. It might be a channel for water to flow across the road so it drains off. If you're going too fast and don't see the dip in time to slow down there's a disturbing jolt and a loud noise when the car drives into the dip.

To explain the symbolism of the metaphor, we sometimes say we 'hit a dip in the road' to mean that our life is difficult or uncomfortable at the moment, or something bad happens suddenly. The song talks about taking a risk. When the lyrics say, 'Fuck it' they mean that we're not going to worry about the consequences of what we're doing. We're taking a risk, living recklessly (driving drunk) and hoping nothing bad happens as a result.

Comment: That was an awesome explanation, thank you very much!